# Is it possible to expand file globbing on the command line in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, glob

I want to know whether it's possible to expand file globbing on the command line in Bash?

Using Readline’s `shell-expand-line` command using `\e\C-e` on the following command line results in only alias expansion and command substitution being performed, but no file globbing expansion:

```
$ ls -lad * $(echo foo)

$ ls -GFh -lad * foo
```

`bind -P`:

```
shell-expand-line can be found on "\e\C-e".
```

Comment: Can't think of a reason for not expanding globs as well. Consider filing a bug report at bug-bash@gnu.org